# PNG - how to know which is the last byte?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, png

I am creating an AIR app that receives PNG data over the socket and they come in in chunks.  How do I know when a byte received is the last byte?

Comment: You can't send the size before the content? That's the standard way of doing it.

Comment: No, can't send size, only the entire PNG stream.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could decode it as it comes in, continuing until you reach the IEND chunk which marks the end of the png. All you need to do is read the 4 byte length and 4 byte chunk type and then skip ahead length+4 bytes, continuing until the chunk type == IEND. Check out the chunk specification for more info.

http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Structure.html

Comment: What byte sequences are IEND? Not specified in doc.

Comment: The chunk type is just 4 ASCII characters, so 0x49454E44

Comment: In that same specs: `IEND` is the last chunk (per specification), but it's not the last set of bytes. The CRC follows: "3.2. Chunk layout".

Comment: Yeah, in order to read the entire PNG you need to go 4 bytes past IEND.  Also note that it's not as easy as just searching for 0x49454E44 in the stream, reading 4 bytes past it and then calling it a day; there is nothing unique about this value that stops it from appearing within any other chunk. You need to write a ghetto chunk parser and only stop reading once you actually reach the IEND chunk.